# Android prefilled DB

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to supply prefilled SQLite DB to my app? I want to use db as ordinary SQLite db which will have tables filled manually and I want to include it into my .apk file.

Comment: Will the SQLite database be used read-only or will you app add data to it?

Comment: refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database

Comment: Refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, include it in your assets folder and copy it into the /databases folder when your application first launches.

Comment: So, I place my db in /assets folder and then...? Could you please explain it?

Comment: See my comment here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753896/externally-generated-sqlite-database-considered-read-only-by-androids-sqliteopen/4753927#4753927

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Comment: The previous code is the correct solution.
I've done this on one of my application, you can find more information here :
http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-ship-application-with-pre-baked.html But finally I decided to stop using this technique, as it implies the database is present twice in your application ( once in the asset folder, once in your application folder ), and for a big database that can be problematic.

Comment: I keep receiving FileNotFound exception when app attempts to open OutputStream. In fact, on first start there is no /database/ dir and app fails to create it.

Comment: Fixed that, it's necessary to create both dir and file explicitly, thnx to all!

Comment: How should I treat journal file? Should I add to assets and copy it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Including in the assets folder is one option (Apk size will be increased.)

How about storing the pre-filled db on any cloud storage service provider and downloading the file on the first run of the app?